# Write Dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I printed a dictionary `final_merged` to a csv file and the output looks like this:

```
2015-08-02 07:00    ['1.00', '0.68', '0.68', '0.00', '9', '19.1', '19.1', '19.1']
```

I'd prefer if it would look like this:

```
 2015-08-02 07:00   1.00  0.68  0.68  0.00  9  19.1  19.1  19.1
```

so I need to get rid of all `'` `[` and `]`
is there an easy way to convert the dictionary?

so far I tried this with two for loops

```
for value in final_merged.items():
line = ''
for values in value[1]:
    line= line+ str(values)+ '\t'
value[1]= line
```

but I've got problems with the str command

print (values[1]) shows:

```
['1.00', '0.68', '0.68', '0.00', '9', '19.1', '19.1', '19.1']
```

The Dictionary looks like:

```
{'2015-08-02 07:00': ['1.00', '0.68', '0.68', '0.00', '9', '19.1', '19.1', '19.1']}
```

I'd like it to look like this

```
2015-08-02 07:00  1.00 0.68 0.68 0.00 9 19.1 19.1 19.1
```

Comment: How does your dictionary look like? And what do you want the dictionary to look like in csv?

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you need if you show a "print value[1]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). You can pass it a list and then it will make a string with all the elements joined into one string. But you can also have a specific string you want inserted between each of them, like `'\t'`.

```
line = line + '\t'.join(values) + '\t'
```

Which should give you the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

thx i solved it:
in te writer at the end of the code I simply entered:

```
w=csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t')
w.writerow(header)
for key, values in sorted(final.merged()):
w.writerow([key] + values)
```

before I had only had

```
w.writerows(sorted(merge_d.items();))
```